# How can I filter a p:tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

I built a tree using Primefaces JSF and I need to add a filter, where it update the data of the tree according to what the user typed.
Does anyone know if this is possible ? I still can not find a solution.

Tree:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primefaces Tree support filters since Primefaces 6.1

```
<p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" filterBy="#{node}" var="node">
   <p:treeNode>
       <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-6-1-final-released/

For older versions, see the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Before PrimeFaces 6.1 this was not possible IN the tree. On older versions just create an input field outside the tree and update the tree after calling a bean that server side updates the data for the tree based on the value of the input field.

Comment: I did what you told me and I could find the tree node. What I did was go through the nodes of the tree and select the filter node and update the tree after calling a bean. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @DéboraCristina, You can also use treeTable in place of tree. The team of primefaces has made great improvements to TreeTable, the filters work well